# Why inputting @ is hitting as %40 in console?

Tags: jquery, validation, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm doing jquery validation for registration form using remote method.

when i input value to email Id in input field, the "@" symbol is taking as %40 and hitting the server as http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcExample/verifyEmailOrPhone-?**emailId=bhagya%40gmail.com**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting is because %40 is the URL-encoded version of @.

You can check it like this:

```
decodeURIComponent('%40');
```

and the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/L62pk36w/) will be @.

So in your case you can use like

```
var decodedUri = decodeURIComponent('http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcExample/verifyEmailOrPhone-?emailId=bhagya@gmail.com');
alert(decodedUri);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L62pk36w/2/)**

Comment: how to decrypt this when i'm inputting

Comment: @BhagyashreeO:- Updated my answer. Please check!

Comment: emailId: {
                  required: true,
                  email: true,
                  remote: {
                   url:'getUserByEmail-',
                   type:'GET',
                   data:{
                   emailId: function()
                      {
                          return $('#emailId').val(); 
                      }
                   }
                  }
              }